# loops around the ears?

Tags: topology

I ve some doubts, I am showing in this pictures, a model than I am using for game purpose.

can this edge loops affects if some of them are moving inside the ears? I ve seen many cg artist to do not mind about rings of edge loops around the ears.

[image]

and consider all the whole topology , may I change something?

Comment: Do you really need to add the additional edges to crease the shape? If so you may think about changing the geometry of the ear to make them work. Otherwise you can just add the *edge creases* (**Shift+E**).

Comment: I wish if the topology for this areas is the correct, should I make a round areaa around the ears? or just simply let the ring of the mouth flows to back of the head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the geometry of the ear to make the creases work. You may leave the edges of the mouth flow to the back of the head- it doesn't matter. The key here is to rearrange the edges flow in the way it creates a loop (see the example below).
[image]

Remember that you can always select the edges to crease then press the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to make them sharper.
[image]